# Interfacing Digital clock with Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, digital

I want to take input from a clock for a specific time and respond to it.

I am taking alarm as input because it will send some signal to a buzzer and I want to decode it through Arduino.

I am using Arduino Uno.

The program I used is as follows:

```
int b = 0;

void setup() {
    pinMode(8, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    b=digitalRead(8);
    Serial.println(b);
    if(digitalRead(8) != 0)
    {
        Serial.println("input in 8");  
    }
    else
        Serial.println("not");

    delay(500);    
}
```

I have removed the buzzer from the clock and connected the terminals to Arduino pin 8 and GND.

But the output is always random (i.e. 0 & 1), no matter if my alarm is on or off.

I cannot find if my program has a flaw or if my approach is just wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that the alarm clock does not provide any voltage level (I mean `GND`) to the  buzzer when it does not have to ring, the circuit is just left "open" then; it will provide a voltage level (depending on your clock power supply) only when the alarm has to ring.

On the other side, your Arduino pin 8 **must** have a voltage level that can be mapped to a `0` (anything between `GND` and `5V/3`) or a `1` (anything between `2x5V/3` and `5V`).

However, in the absence of alarm, the input is left "dangling" (no voltage level at all). In CMOS technology, leaving an input pin dangling will make it randomly take `0` and `1` levels as you described.

Fortunately, the solution to this problem should be easy: you just have to force a `0` level to pin 8, by connecting it to `GND` through a resistor. I generally use 10K or 15K for that resistor. This is called a "pulldown" resistor:

- when the alarm does not provide any voltage, the input pin level will be "pulled down" to `GND`, ie `0`.
- when the alarm provides a 5V (see important remark below) to the input pin, then it will be seen as `1`.

**IMPORTANT**: you have to make sure that your alarm clock, when ringing, provides a voltage that is not higher than 5V (it would grill your UNO, or more precisely the ATmega328 of your UNO) and is at least ~3V to be "recognized" as `1`.

**NOTE**: it is likely that solving this first issue will not be enough to make your complete program work, because your alarm clock probably does not send a continuous voltage to your buzzer but and alternate one to make it ring, hence you will get successive `1` and `0` at high speed (between 100Hz and 100Hz I would say) in your program. If that is the case please open another question as the solution for that specific issue is disconnected from the current one (random `1` and `0`).

Comment: A 10k pull-down resistor should also help to stabilize the signal.

Comment: A capacitor could help smooth the 100 Hz (or whatever) signal when the alarm is on.

Comment: If you have access to an oscilloscope, it would be beneficial to take a reading of what output the clock makes when the alarm is on. (ie whether it is AC or DC and what voltage it is).